# Calculate percentage discount of multiple products on a product listing page

Tags: jquery, percentage, price, discount

Hi i'm trying to work out the percentage discount of products that are on sale on a product listing page which have a was and now price.

I've got the code working to get the percentage discount, but i can't seem to get it to work dynamically for each product. As at the moment it'll run the calculation then print the same percentage discount per product, and even for products that are full price.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
setTimeout(function discountPrice() {
  $('.product-slab__price').each(function() {
    var pattern = /[^0-9\.]/g;
    var wasPrice = parseFloat($(".product-price__primary .product-price__was").text().replace(pattern, "")) / 100;
    var newPrice = parseFloat($(".product-price__primary .product-price__value--discounted").text().replace(pattern, "") / 100);
    var subtractPrice = (Math.abs(wasPrice - newPrice));
    var dividePrice = (Math.abs(subtractPrice / wasPrice));
    var multiplyPrice = (Math.abs(dividePrice * 100));
    $('.discountPercentage').html(multiplyPrice.toFixed(0) + "&#37");
  });
}, 500);
```

```css
.product-price__was {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.product-price__value.product-price__value--discounted {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__was">Was &euro;10,00</span>
    <span class="product-price__value product-price__value--discounted">Now &euro;8,00</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage" > </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__was">&euro;15,00</span>
    <span class="product-price__value product-price__value--discounted">&euro;10,00</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage"></span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__value">&euro;15,90</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting *all* the elements in the DOM with those classes as you iterate through the loop.

Instead, you need to target the elements with those classes relevant to the current `.product-slab__price` in the iteration. To do that use the `this` keyword and the `find()` method:

```js
setTimeout(function discountPrice() {
  var pattern = /[^0-9\.]/g;

  $('.product-slab__price:has(.product-price__value--discounted)').each(function() {
    let $slab = $(this);
    var wasPrice = parseFloat($slab.find(".product-price__primary .product-price__was").text().replace(pattern, "")) / 100;
    var newPrice = parseFloat($slab.find(".product-price__primary .product-price__value--discounted").text().replace(pattern, "") / 100);

    var subtractPrice = Math.abs(wasPrice - newPrice);
    var dividePrice = Math.abs(subtractPrice / wasPrice);
    var multiplyPrice = Math.abs(dividePrice * 100);
    
    $slab.find('.discountPercentage').html(multiplyPrice.toFixed(0) + "&#37");
  });
}, 500);
```

```css
.product-price__was {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.product-price__value.product-price__value--discounted {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__was">Was &euro;10,00</span>
    <span class="product-price__value product-price__value--discounted">Now &euro;8,00</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage"> </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__was">&euro;15,00</span>
    <span class="product-price__value product-price__value--discounted">&euro;10,00</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage"></span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__value">&euro;15,90</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that as the regex content is static it can be defined outside the loop.

Comment: [my `,this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66531024/295783) is more elegant in my opinion and I do not get NaN

Comment: Arguable, as I find it easier to read the target element at the start of the statement to follow the selection logic. Thanks for the note about the isNaN output.

Comment: Thank you both, going to go with your answer @RoryMcCrossan on this.

Comment: I've got another question on this. As this will be ran on a product listing page, when a user clicks on load more products the script would need to run again. But when i do this the products that are on sale on page 1 gets the percentage discount loaded again. How would i go about ensuring that the script doesn't run if a percentage discount already exists on a product?

Comment: That would depend on how you load the content. Put simply, you'd amend the `.product-slab__price:has(..)` selector to only look at the content you're creating before appending it. I'd suggest starting a new question with details of your AJAX request if you have issues implementing it

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- use `,this` to stay in the scope of the current slab
- test multiplyPrice is a number
- move the regexp since you do not need to create it every time

---

No need to

- go via .product-price__primary in the code you show
- parseFloat since you do not add anywhere. A unary plus `+wasPrice` can be used if you DO need to add

```js
const pattern = /[^0-9\.]/g,
  discountPrice = function() {
    $('.product-slab__price').each(function() {
      const wasPrice = $(".product-price__was", this).text().replace(pattern, "") / 100,
        newPrice = $(".product-price__value--discounted", this).text().replace(pattern, "") / 100,
        subtractPrice = Math.abs(wasPrice - newPrice),
        dividePrice = Math.abs(subtractPrice / wasPrice),
        multiplyPrice = Math.abs(dividePrice * 100);

      if (!isNaN(multiplyPrice)) $('.discountPercentage', this).html(multiplyPrice.toFixed(0) + "&#37");
    });
  };

setTimeout(discountPrice, 500);
```

```css
.product-price__was {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.product-price__value.product-price__value--discounted {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__was">Was &euro;10,00</span>
    <span class="product-price__value product-price__value--discounted">Now &euro;8,00</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage"> </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__was">&euro;15,00</span>
    <span class="product-price__value product-price__value--discounted">&euro;10,00</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage"></span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="product-slab__price">
  <div class="product-price__primary">
    <span class="product-price__value">&euro;15,90</span>
    <span class="discountPercentage"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```